# What does (R) and (TM) mean in Intel brand name?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7

I know this question is stupid but could anyone explain it.

What does (R) and (TM) mean in Intel brand name?

**For example:**

> Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2670QM

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if off topic...

Comment: Feel free to delete if you want!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What does (R) and (TM) mean in Intel brand name?

The same as when it appears in any other brand name or publication.

(R) or ® stands for [Registered Trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registered_trademark_symbol):

> The registered trademark symbol (®) is a symbol that provides notice that the preceding word or symbol is a trademark or service mark that has been registered with a national trademark office. A trademark is a symbol, word, or words legally registered or established by use as representing a company or product

(TM) or ™ stands for [Trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark):

> A trademark, trade mark, or trade-mark is a recognizable sign, design, or expression which identifies products or services of a particular source from those of others, although trademarks used to identify services are usually called service marks. The trademark owner can be an individual, business organization, or any legal entity. A trademark may be located on a package, a label, a voucher, or on the product itself. For the sake of corporate identity, trademarks are being displayed on company buildings.

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the detailed explanation! I've got it now. Every symbol has its own meaning.

Answer (score 2):

(TM) or ™ is for trademarks that are not necessarily registered with a trademark office, the US Patent and Trademark Office in the USA. It means the company believes they have a right to that trademark, even though it's not officially registered.

(R) or ® is for trademarks that are registered.

Answer (score -1):

There are two different symbols are used to represent the trademark (TM) and (R). Where TM represents a trademark registration is under process whereas (R) means the trademark is a registered one.

Here is a trick to type both the symbols on the keyboard, know how: https://www.quickcompany.in/articles/how-to-type-the-registered-trademark-symbol

Comment: Welcome to Super User. OP didn't ask how to type the symbols...